# What's going on with my Matcap and how do I fix it?

Tags: matcaps

Whenever I try to put a Matcap on my object, it turns white. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the matcap, it is most likely your geometry. Try recalculating normals with `Ctrl+N`in edit mode.

Comment: Could you [upload your file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and post the link here? It might help people identify the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I think its graphic driver problem

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the correct .dll file from here:
http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/
and put it in the same directory as blender.exe.

Explained here:
https://developer.blender.org/T50371